# Running "sudo /sbin/service --status-all" restarts a service (Apache)

Tags: linux, apache, service, sudo

I'm looking to understand how running the command "sudo /sbin/service --status-all" on a RedHat 6.7 64bit system could restart Apache?

I've always used this command to list all running and stopped services, this is the first time I've seen it restart a service though. Is this down to a bad Apache config or can issuing this command restart services in certain circumstances?

Update:

The status of httpd is that it is stopped:

> sudo /etc/rc.d/init.d/httpd status
>
> httpd is stopped
>
> sudo /etc/init.d/httpd status
>
> httpd is stopped

If I run "sudo /sbin/service --status-all" I see:

> X is installed
>
> Y is running...
>
> X is stopped
>
> httpd (pid xxx) already running
>
> root     xxx     1  0 18:10 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -f
>   /httpd.conf -k start

Comment: Since that option runs all init scripts with the option "status" this means that the init script for that apache service has to restart that service when call like that. This is not the default, but if that script has been exchanged or modified that certainly could be possible.

Comment: This could well be it. I tried running "sudo service httpd status" and did not see Apache restart.Are different init scripts used when calling "sudo service httpd status" and "sudo /sbin/service --status-all"?

Comment: No, it is "the" init scripts that are called.

Comment: Make makes you think that it was your service call that restarted the apache http server?

Comment: It was definitely the "service --status all" call, I can see the output say "httpd (pid XXXX) already running" which means it's trying to restart it. If I'm not mistaken, isn't running "sudo /etc/init.d/httpd status" the equivalent of what should have been run by this command?

Comment: That does really not look like the output of a call to `service --status-all`. Would you mind adding some of that output to your question? There is an `edit` link for that.

Comment: Updated with the output I see.